# Constructor is setting fields to default values

Tags: java

```
package animal;

class AnimalHumanDogDemo
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Animal chicken = new Animal(1.53, 53.2, 14.2, "red junglefowl");

        Human Alex = new Human(1.73, 62.3, 52.0, "Ape", "Greek", "Programmer", 1234);

        Dog Betty = new Dog(0.53, 21.6, 8.3, "wolf", "chiouaoua", 214, false, "white");

        String a = chicken.toString();

        System.out.println(a);

        double b = Alex.Yearly_salary();
        System.out.println(b);

        String c = Alex.toString();
        System.out.println(c);

        Boolean d = Betty.Expensive_Purebred();
        System.out.println(d);

        String e = Betty.toString();
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

When I run main the results are always null for strings and bollean variables, 
and '0' for everything else.
I created the contructor in Animal,Human and dog classes the same way I've been doing always.
I can provide the classes' code if needed.

Comment: Can you show us the `Animal` class code alone (we assume rest also follow the same concept)?

Comment: looks like a basic java questions. Refer to documentation and if you have question after spending more time on it rephrase the question.

Comment: I forgot to mention that classes Human and Dog extend the class Animal and in the constructor i use `super()`

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include additional information

Comment: Also, please learn about Java naming contentions. Variables and methods always should start lowercase

Comment: the question was answered by Blue Nite

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the variables in the constructor.

```
public class Animal 
{
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private String des;

    public Animal(double x, double y, String des)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.des = des;
    }
}
```

As mentioned by  cricket_007 `x = x` can cause problems.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that `x =x` can cause the problem  in the question